# How to delete specific parts of a dynamic created list in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dynamic, html-lists

[Shoppinglist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbBR0.png)

Hey you,

I'm currently working on a fairly simple shopping list to familiarize myself with javascript.

As you can see in the picture, I want to delete the element next to it when I click on the trashcan.
But this doesn't quite work as one would imagine and only deletes the top item from my list no matter which trashcan i click on.

My function to create the elements

```
function addFun(){
    // * List 
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.setAttribute('class', 'list_element');
    li.textContent = input.value;
    liste.appendChild(li);
    if(input.value !== ''){
        // * Checkbox
        const checkbox = document.createElement('input');
        checkbox.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');
        li.insertBefore(checkbox, li.childNodes[0]);
        input.value = '';
        // * trashcan
        const trash = document.createElement('img');
        trash.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/3209/3209887.png');
        trash.setAttribute('class', 'image');
        li.appendChild(trash);
    }
}
```

My Eventlistener to remove the elements

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('image')){
        deleteIt();
    }
});

function deleteIt(){
    const li = document.querySelector('.list_element');
    li.remove();
}
```

It took me a long time to get the event handler working as I had never heard of event bubbling before.
I tried a bit with "this" to find a solution, but I wasn't quite sure what it meant in the context

I would be very happy if someone could look over it and maybe give me a solution or a tip

Comment: `document.querySelector()` returns the first matching item. You should probably pass the click event to deleteIt()` and use that to determine which element was clicked and should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can determine the button that was clicked by `e.target`.  From the button you can locate the LI to delete using [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/element/closest)

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('image')){
        deleteIt(e.target);
    }
});

function deleteIt(whichButton){
    const li = whichButton.closest("li");
    li.remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `deleteIt()` function is not getting the `li` that should be deleted.

You should pass the target button that is clicked to the `deleteIt()`.

In this way;

```
    document.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if(e.target.classList.contains('image')){
        deleteIt(e.target);
    }
});

function deleteIt(target){
    const li = target.closest("li");
    li.remove();
}
```

This way the `deleteIt()` know which element to delete pricesely.

I am also new to programming. Sorry if it doesn't help.